# TableAdapter and Unicode?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, internationalization, globalization, tableadapter

Working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional, using C#, with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have been tasked with taking an existing application, and making changes so that it can receive multiple languages in its text boxes without needing to configure ahead of time what language is to be used.

To ensure that I am doing this correctly, I have created a new table in the database, called Language.  If I can get things working correctly with [Language], I should be able to get it all working.  The field in question is `MotherTongueLanguageName`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Language](
[LanguageID] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[LanguageName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[MotherTongueLanguageName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL)
```

I preload the table with content:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Language]
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO [Language] VALUES ('English','English') -- 1
INSERT INTO [Language] VALUES ('French','Français') -- 2
INSERT INTO [Language] VALUES ('Spanish','Español') -- 3
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

And on my web page, it all looks perfect.  When I try to enter Russian and `русский` from the web page, it hits the database with `???????` in the `MotherTongueLanguageName`.  I want to be able to do this without setting a specific culture or uiCulture, if possible.

I have already edited my MasterPage.master file and have added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to the `<head>`, and `accept-charset="utf-8"` to the `<form>` tag.

I have even added `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` to the Custom HTTP headers in IIS, thought I'm hoping that's not actually necessary.

The web page does use a TableAdapter to connect the grids and entry fields to the database, and I'm wondering if there's anything in there that's reverting my Unicode text back to ASCII.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm fresh out of guesses, and Google has helped me just about as much as it can with the search terms I've been using.

-- New Info --

All of my web page -> Database linkages are stored in a file called DBDataSet.xsd.  When I right-click on an empty area within this form, I get the option to Add -> TableAdapter...  When I do this, I get a wizard that walks me through `Choose Your Data Connection`, then `Choose a Command Type` (I choose `Use existing stored procedures`), then `Bind Commands to Existing Stored Procedures`.  I select my Select, Insert, Update and Delete sprocs, each of which accept as parameters both VarChar and NVarChar data for the appropriate columns.  It then takes me to `Choose Methods to Generate`, and I select both `Fill a DataTable` and `Return a DataTable`.

All of this happens automatically, and a bunch of code is generated behind-the-scenes.  When I search the DBDataSet.Designer.cs file for references to `MotherTongueLanguageName`, I don't see any code that differentiates it from other columns that are just VarChars.  For example:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private void InitClass() {
        this.columnLanguageName = new global::System.Data.DataColumn("LanguageName", typeof(string), null, global::System.Data.MappingType.Element);
        base.Columns.Add(this.columnLanguageName);
        this.columnLanguageID = new global::System.Data.DataColumn("LanguageID", typeof(byte), null, global::System.Data.MappingType.Element);
        base.Columns.Add(this.columnLanguageID);
        this.columnLanguageAbbrev = new global::System.Data.DataColumn("LanguageAbbrev", typeof(string), null, global::System.Data.MappingType.Element);
        base.Columns.Add(this.columnLanguageAbbrev);
        this.columnMotherTongueLanguageName = new global::System.Data.DataColumn("MotherTongueLanguageName", typeof(string), null, global::System.Data.MappingType.Element);
        base.Columns.Add(this.columnMotherTongueLanguageName);
        this.columnLanguageColour = new global::System.Data.DataColumn("LanguageColour", typeof(string), null, global::System.Data.MappingType.Element);
        base.Columns.Add(this.columnLanguageColour);
        this.Constraints.Add(new global::System.Data.UniqueConstraint("Constraint1", new global::System.Data.DataColumn[] {
                        this.columnLanguageID}, true));
        this.columnLanguageName.AllowDBNull = false;
        this.columnLanguageName.MaxLength = 30;
        this.columnLanguageID.AllowDBNull = false;
        this.columnLanguageID.ReadOnly = true;
        this.columnLanguageID.Unique = true;
        this.columnLanguageAbbrev.AllowDBNull = false;
        this.columnLanguageAbbrev.MaxLength = 3;
        this.columnMotherTongueLanguageName.AllowDBNull = false;
        this.columnMotherTongueLanguageName.MaxLength = 30;
        this.columnLanguageColour.MaxLength = 10;
    }
```

Both `LanguageName` and `MotherTongueLanguageName` use `typeof(string)`, even though one is a VarChar, and the other is an NVarChar.  Is this correct?

Also:

```
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
    private void InitAdapter() {
        this._adapter = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
        global::System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping tableMapping = new global::System.Data.Common.DataTableMapping();
        tableMapping.SourceTable = "Table";
        tableMapping.DataSetTable = "GetLanguages";
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("LanguageName", "LanguageName");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("LanguageID", "LanguageID");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("LanguageAbbrev", "LanguageAbbrev");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("MotherTongueLanguageName", "MotherTongueLanguageName");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("LanguageColour", "LanguageColour");
        this._adapter.TableMappings.Add(tableMapping);
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = "dbo.DeleteLanguage";
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@LanguageID", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 10, 0, "LanguageID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.InsertCommand = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "dbo.AddLanguage";
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@LanguageName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@LanguageAbbrev", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageAbbrev", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@MotherTongueLanguageName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "MotherTongueLanguageName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@LanguageColour", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageColour", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "dbo.EditLanguage";
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@OldLanguageID", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 10, 0, "LanguageID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@OldLanguageName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@OldLanguageAbbrev", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageAbbrev", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@OldMotherTongueLanguageName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "MotherTongueLanguageName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@OldLanguageColour", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageColour", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@NewLanguageName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@NewLanguageAbbrev", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageAbbrev", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@NewMotherTongueLanguageName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "MotherTongueLanguageName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@NewLanguageColour", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "LanguageColour", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
    }
```

Shouldn't the generated code be referencing `global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar` instead of `global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar`?  If I make these changes directly to the generated code, the changes get blown away as soon as I even refresh the DBDataSet.xsd file.

This is an existing project, so I need to continue with the manner by which data is fetched from and put to the database.  What do I need to do to get the data from the webpage, through the TableAdapter, to the database correctly?

Comment: Which collation is used by the database? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I was under the impression that this affects sorting only, but I tried adding my cryllic text into the script, and got the same thing.

Comment: In (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176557(v=sql.80).aspx), it says:

_SQL collations control:
The code page used for storing non-Unicode data in Microsoft® SQL Server™.
The rules governing how SQL Server sorts and compares characters stored in both Unicode and non-Unicode data types.

Choose a SQL collation if:
You use the replication feature with existing instances of SQL Server version 6.5 or SQL Server version 7.0
Your application code depends on the behaviors of the previous SQL Server collations._

It seems I need a collation, but I do not want one...

Comment: You need to add the code that takes the form inputs and store it in the db.

Comment: Actually, it's looking like it may be a SQL Server thing.  I tried adding the unicode text direct via SQL SMS 2012, and it worked.  I tried adding it via an Insert script in a Query window in SQL SMS 2012, and it didn't.  Is there a different forum I can post this question to?

Comment: Doh!  I realize my mistake with the script.  'русский' needs to be N'русский' when being inserted as text within the INSERT.  So, back to the original question; do I need to do anything special with the TableAdapter when handling unicode data?

Comment: Again: show your code. I can't reason about code I don't see and your last comments makes be a little bit worried...

Comment: I edited the original post to include some of the auto-generated code that I believe may be responsible for the data not reaching the database.  If there is other auto-generated code that is relevant to this discussion that I have not added, please direct me to where I can find it, and I'll include it.

Comment: Can you add the Create statement for dbo.AddLanguage , dbo.EditLanguage and GetLanguages

Comment: I can, and I'll also add some suggestions I got from DaniWeb, explaining how to edit the settings in the TableAdapter builder to correct the linkage from VarChar to NVarChar, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I was looking for at [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/479847/tableadapter-and-unicode).

The problem was that it wasn't clear that I needed to use the DataSet designer to change my new Unicode columns from `DataType:AnsiString` (the default) to `DataType:String`.  As soon as I do that, the designer changes the `ProviderType` from `VarChar` to `NVarChar`.  I had thought that if you were creating a new TableAdapter from scratch, that it should recognize that the column was an `NVarChar` and do this automatically.  Now I realize I simply need to do that extra step.

Also, as we are using a separate TableAdapter for storing all of the non-CRUD stored procedures, I need to do the same with that, ensuring that the data being passed stays Unicode.